# Historical Aerial Imagery of Ivory Coast

Tags: data-request, historical, aerial-photography, ivory-coast

I'm looking for historical aerial imagery for Ivory Coast (Cote d'Ivoire).

My first web searches have turned up nothing, but I know the French (and possibly the Soviets) created basemaps of the region in the post-colonial period (therefore there must be aerial imagery from which these maps were created).

Anyone have suggestions of where to start looking?